# How to test for differences in SQL record to Model record

Tags: sql, json, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a SQL database that i need to keep synchronized with information that gets pulled down from an API as JSON.

Is there a way to quickly check for difference in the record in the SQL database against the Deserialized JSON object.  Without having to check each individual field in both. And then update those changes in the SQL record.

The app is in MVC 5 with entity framework 6 and I'm using linq to access the database and have all the JSON Deserialized into models.

Comment: "And then update those changes in the SQL record." You could just update everything, right? Unchanged fields would remain unchanged and the changed fields would propagate to the existing record.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah i could. Is there a quick way to do that instead of writing out Column = Json.Column for each one.  I'm still new to this and there are a lot of fields and linked tables

Comment: Have you looked into [automapper](http://automapper.org/) before?

Comment: I haven't. That's awesome.  Will be using that.  Thanks